# Cannot remotely read from a MSMQ 6.3 private queue cross forest

Tags: msmq, rpc

I am connecting to a `MSMQ 6.3` private queue in workgroup mode on a Windows Server 2012R2 machine.  This is a cross forest connection.  I've gotten to where I can send, but I still cannot receive.  I've done everything in John Breakwell's posts. I've given the correct domain user, Anonymous Logon and Everyone Full Control.

I've added the registry entries `NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient` and `AllowNonauthenticatedRPC`.
Disable un-athenticated RPC calls is not checked.
I ran Wireshark and I can see traffic coming in to port `135` then getting passed off to port `2105`.  There it gets `access_denied`.
I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is the traffic allowed through the firewall on port 2105?

Comment: Might need to get more detailed RPC logging with "Enabling Extended Error Information" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373803%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: What are the queue properties? Importantly, is 'Authenticated' ticked or the Privacy Level set?

Comment: Firewall is turned off.  I've tried it with authenticated checked and not.  Privacy level is set to "None".

Comment: OK, this is access from one domain to another in a different forest but that isn't relevant as:

 1. MSMQ is in workgroup mode, not AD-integrated
 2. The queue is private, not public, so the queue name doesn't need an AD lookup.
 3. The request should be using Direct Format Name in the address (correct me if that's not the case).
 4. Sending works so forest trusts aren't a problem

Comment: The Firewall has been disabled so all ports should be open.

Receiving messages is similar to accessing a file share. See if you can set up a shared folder (with similar anonymous/everyone permissions) on the remote machine and access it from the local machine. If that works, it's not a permissions issue.

Comment: Check NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient and AllowNonauthenticatedRPC are both DWORDs under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security